# How to match `\b` in regex in PetitParserDart?

Tags: dart, petitparser

`\b` is the "world boundary" in regular expression, how to match it in PetitParserDart?

I tried:

```
pattern("\b") & word().plus() & pattern("\b")
```

But it doesn't match anything. The patten above I want is `\b\w+\b` in regular expression.

---

My real problem is:

I want to treat the `render` as a token, only if it's a standalone word.

Following is true:

```
render
to render the page
render()
@render[it]
```

Following is not:

```
rerender
rendering
render123
```

I can't use `string("render").trim()` here since it will eat up the spaces around it. So I want the `\b` but it seems not be supported by PetitParserDart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parser returned by `pattern` only looks at a single character. Have a look at the [tests](https://github.com/renggli/PetitParserDart/blob/e03d5a590e9e2b7ad197dce186f594f59e8239fa/test/core_test.dart#L447) for some examples.

A first approximation of the regular expression `\b\w+\b` would be:

```
word().neg() & word().plus() & word().not()
```

However, this requires a non-word character at the beginning of the parsed string. You can avoid this problem by removing `word().neg()` and making sure that the caller starts at a valid place.

The problem you describe is common when using parsing expression grammars. You can typically solve it by reordering the choices accordingly, or by using the logical predicates like `and()` and `not()`. For example the [Smalltalk grammar](https://github.com/renggli/PetitParserDart/blob/master/lib/src/smalltalk/grammar.dart#L221) defines the token `true` as follows:

```
def('trueToken', _token('true') & word().not());
```

This avoids that the token parser accidentally consumes part of a variable called `trueblood`.